# Display Pandas DataFrame and Matplotlib in JupyterNotebook plot side by side

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe from Pandas

```py
my_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(5), 'b': range(20, 30, 2)})
my_dataframe
```

```py
a   b
0   0   20
1   1   22
2   2   24
3   3   26
4   4   28
```

- And a plot from Matplotlib

```py
plt.bar(my_dataframe['a'].index, my_dataframe['a'].values)
```

[image]

What I wanna do is display both of them using IPython and don't losing the default df output format. The first solution of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286696/how-to-display-dataframe-next-to-plot-in-jupyter-notebook/45287049) link answared my question but don't have this format that I talked about. I want the following exemple in the same output cell:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing the CSS ordering directive from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783027/jupyter-notebook-display-two-pandas-tables-side-by-side) gives you a partial solution, but unfortunately the table is on the left and the plot is on the right.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd   
from IPython.display import display, HTML
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

CSS = """
.output {
    flex-direction: row;
}
"""

display(HTML('<style>{}</style>'.format(CSS)))

my_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(5), 'b': range(20, 30, 2)})

plt.bar(my_dataframe['a'].index, my_dataframe['a'].values)
my_dataframe
```

[Table and plot side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zbw5.png)

I believe the reason that the plot is rendered last, putting it to the right, is because of the `%matplotlib inline` directive that is part of most standard IPython configurations. If I understand correctly, the directive causes the plot to be output last, after the table is rendered.