# Python: build object of Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has `dtype=object`, i.e. categorical variables, for which I'd like to have the counts of each level of. I'd like the result to be a pretty summary of all categorical variables.

To achieve the aforementioned goals, I tried the following:

(line 1) grab the names of all object-type variables

(line 2) count the number of observations for each level (`a`, `b` of `v1`)

(line 3) rename the column so it reads "count"

```
stringCol = list(df.select_dtypes(include=['object'])) # list object of categorical variables
a = df.groupby(stringCol[0]).agg({stringCol[0]: 'count'})
a = a.rename(index=str, columns={stringCol[0]: 'count'}); a
    count
v1  
a   1279
b   2382
```

I'm not sure how to elegantly get the following result where all string column counts are printed. Like so (only `v1` and `v4` shown, but should be able to print such results for a variable number of columns):

```
    count       count
v1           v4
a   1279     l  32
b   2382     u  3055
             y  549
```

The way I can think of doing it is:

1. select one element of `stringCol`
2. calculate the count of for each group of the column.
3. store the result in a Pandas dataframe.
4. store the Pandas dataframe in an object (list?)
5. repeat
6. if last element of `stringCol` is done, break.

but there must be a better way than that, just not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simpliest is use loop:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abaaee'),
                   'B':list('abbccf'),
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aacbbb')})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  a  7  1  5  a
1  b  b  8  3  3  a
2  a  b  9  5  6  c
3  a  c  4  7  9  b
4  e  c  2  1  2  b
5  e  f  3  0  4  b
```

---

```
stringCol = list(df.select_dtypes(include=['object']))

for c in stringCol:
    a = df[c].value_counts().rename_axis(c).to_frame('count')
    #alternative
    #a = df.groupby(c)[c].count().to_frame('count')
    print (a)

   count
A       
a      3
e      2
b      1
   count
B       
b      2
c      2
a      1
f      1
   count
F       
b      3
a      2
c      1
```

---

For `list of DataFrames` use `list comprehension`:

```
dfs = [df[c].value_counts().rename_axis(c).to_frame('count') for c in stringCol]
print (dfs)

[   count
A       
a      3
e      2
b      1,    count
B       
b      2
c      2
a      1
f      1,    count
F       
b      3
a      2
c      1]
```

Comment: yeah, this is much better. didn't know about those functions and hard to learn about their existence through google w/o knowing relevant key terms. is there a way to make them print side-by-side to avoid having to scroll through the results? relevant bc may have a number of columns on the order of 1x10^n where n>=2

Comment: @user2205916 - Yes, but it is a bit complicated, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38801975/2901002)

Comment: in order to use the solution in the link you posted, i'd have to create a dataframe for each iteration through the loop. then, i think i'd have to store each dataframe into another object (which would be?)

Comment: Yes, it is possible create list of DataFrames. Give me a sec

Comment: thanks. almost done. the final solution will look like: `display_side_by_side(dfs[0], dfs[1], dfs[2])` what is a better way to enumerate all of the dataframes in `dfs`? i tried: `display_side_by_side([dfs[c] for c in range(len(dfs))])` but that won't work

Comment: OK, I am going test it.

Comment: that is a great trick. is there a term or reference i can look up for more information on it? not sure what search terms to use

Comment: You can check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

Comment: Last question: how to print with thousands separator? I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators but can't get it to work with: `stringCol = list(df.select_dtypes(include=['object'])) # list object of categorical variables
dfs = [df[c].value_counts().rename_axis(c).to_frame('count') for c in stringCol]`
`display_side_by_side(*dfs)`.

Comment: You can use `dfs = [df[c].value_counts().rename_axis(c).to_frame('count').applymap("{:,}".format) for c in stringCol]
`

Comment: great. how do i round decimal places for: `[df[c].value_counts(normalize=True).rename_axis(c).to_frame('count').applymap("{:,}".format) for c in stringCol]` ? I tried adding `.applymap(lambda x: round(x,1))` but it takes issue with the `value_counts`

Comment: @user2205916 - Hmmm, it seems round is not necessay, because count values, so nevet float, alwys get integer. Possible minimal value is 0, then, 1, 2 to N. But if need it join with format `dfs = [df[c].value_counts().rename_axis(c).to_frame('count').applymap(lambda x: "{:,}".format(round(x, 1))) for c in stringCol]`

Comment: thx, you've been a great help perfecting this. `.value_counts(normalize=True)` actually produces floats because it gives proportions. i.e. 0.9 values are "true" and 0.1 values are "false"