# How do I display more than one pandas describe() output in a single jupyter cell?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, jupyter-lab

This is a really basic question but I haven't been able to find an answer:

In Jupyter, if I execute two pandas `df.describe()` calls in the same cell, only the last one's output is displayed. The same is true for `.info()`, `.head()` etc. etc.

**How do I persuade Jupyter and pandas to display all `N` of the above outputs sequentially as intended, with the same tabular formatting that is the default for a single output?**

FWIW example code would be:

```py
df1.describe()
#...
df2.describe()
dfN.describe() # Only the result of the final call is displayed
```

Points from comments addressed:

1. `print(df1.describe())` works, but does not render the table identically to how it is rendered by `describe()` itself.
2. Displaying two pandas tables *side-by-side* ([Jupyter notebook display two pandas tables side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783027/jupyter-notebook-display-two-pandas-tables-side-by-side)) may work, but doesn't scale to `N` tables.

Comment: use print() function

Comment: @DevenRamani How to maintain tabular pretty print?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this  similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783027/jupyter-notebook-display-two-pandas-tables-side-by-side

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyter notebook display two pandas tables side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783027/jupyter-notebook-display-two-pandas-tables-side-by-side)

Comment: If you need more than one, why don't you combine them with `pd.concat()`, since the output of `describe()` is also a dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [configure](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html#the-config-magic) your current session and specify what values to show by [InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html#configtrait-InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity):

```py
%config InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = 'all'
```

[image]